# Unknown sendmail entries in logfile

Tags: sendmail

I've just received loads of junk mail to a capture all mailbox. I've looked at the server logs and can see below. I'm using `sendmail`, relaying is disabled but don't understand what they mean.

```
Oct 1 12:26:40 bookingwidget sendmail[27713]: s91CQdhW027713: from=<>, size=48016, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<20141001122637.2074B33DA@usch1smtp02.grouponinc.net>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=[204.17.255.34]
Oct 1 12:26:40 bookingwidget sendmail[27715]: s91CQdhW027713: to=<item@bookingwidget.co.uk>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=78214, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Oct 1 12:26:40 bookingwidget sendmail[27714]: s91CQdJY027714: from=<>, size=48012, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<20141001122637.5C83C33D9@usch1smtp02.grouponinc.net>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=[204.17.255.34]
Oct 1 12:26:40 bookingwidget sendmail[27717]: s91CQdJY027714: to=<item@bookingwidget.co.uk>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=78210, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Oct 1 12:26:42 bookingwidget sendmail[27719]: s91CQfSs027719: from=<>, size=50102, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<bada421c-9fef-402d-adab-62870704f369@osil.co.uk>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=mail.oceanscientific.co.uk [217.45.154.122]
Oct 1 12:26:43 bookingwidget sendmail[27720]: s91CQfSs027719: to=<item@bookingwidget.co.uk>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=local, pri=80324, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Oct 1 12:26:43 bookingwidget sendmail[27722]: s91CQhwv027722: from=<>, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=1, proto=SMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=mx13.mail.eu.clara.net [81.171.239.23]
Oct 1 12:26:44 bookingwidget sendmail[27723]: s91CQhpC027723: from=<>, size=3536, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<SS16339-20@mr3.devon.gov.uk>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=mr3.devon.gov.uk [159.15.129.83]
Oct 1 12:26:44 bookingwidget sendmail[27724]: s91CQhpC027723: to=<item@bookingwidget.co.uk>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=33740, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Oct 1 12:26:45 bookingwidget sendmail[27726]: s91CQjdC027726: from=<>, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=1, proto=SMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=smtpa.scotland.net [194.247.64.1]
Oct 1 12:26:45 bookingwidget sendmail[27727]: s91CQjWU027727: from=<>, size=6107, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<eb603db8-fb93-45bd-a959-c67b36de84f3@necgroup.co.uk>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=gateway.necgroup.co.uk [213.86.71.240]
Oct 1 12:26:45 bookingwidget sendmail[27728]: s91CQjWU027727: to=<item@bookingwidget.co.uk>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=36321, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Oct 1 12:26:46 bookingwidget sendmail[27730]: s91CQkvC027730: from=<>, size=705, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<E1XZIzT-0006b1-Sp@pop.scotland.net>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=chicken.scotland.net [194.247.64.31]
Oct 1 12:26:46 bookingwidget sendmail[27731]: s91CQkvC027730: to=<item@bookingwidget.co.uk>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30915, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Oct 1 12:26:46 bookingwidget sendmail[27732]: s91CQkwh027732: from=<>, size=51603, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<Ij3kuwwlR00001d38@dc1ukexmbs001.Uk.ProvidentInternational.co.uk>, proto=SMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=mx2.ipfin.co.uk [62.60.9.99]
Oct 1 12:26:46 bookingwidget sendmail[27734]: s91CQkwh027732: to=<item@bookingwidget.co.uk>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=81828, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Oct 1 12:26:46 bookingwidget sendmail[27736]: s91CQkn6027736: from=<>, size=53352, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<a857ac64-9c4c-45b4-a413-769bcdd0cb5f@DBXPR05MB0607.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=mail-db3on0061.outbound.protection.outlook.com [157.55.234.61]
Oct 1 12:26:46 bookingwidget sendmail[27739]: s91CQkWi027739: from=<>, size=725, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<E1XZIzU-0006bB-D5@pop.scotland.net>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=chicken.scotland.net [194.247.64.31]
Oct 1 12:26:46 bookingwidget sendmail[27740]: s91CQkWi027739: to=<item@bookingwidget.co.uk>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30935, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Oct 1 12:26:46 bookingwidget sendmail[27742]: s91CQkBv027742: from=<>, size=3472, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<c65e40d6746547f8a40cf374c935e8dd@AMXPR01MB007.eurprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=mail-db3on0058.outbound.protection.outlook.com [157.55.234.58]
```

Comment: Use e.g. http://www.mailradar.com/openrelay/ to test if relaying is really disabled.

Answer (score 3):

Those messages are "bounces". They are usually caused by someone else sending an email to one of your users, and when the email can't be delivered, the mail server will generate a bounce message. You can tell them from regular messages because bounce messages always have the envelope sender `<>`.

In this case, it would appear that the original message had the envelope sender `<item@bookingwidget.co.uk>`, and so your mailserver is trying to deliver information about the failed message to that address.

You will need to look at one of the actual messages in order to figure out what the original message was and why it couldn't be delivered.

Comment: Thanks for reply, looks like a spammer is using our domain name to send spam and all the bounce backs are hitting our grab all email address. Anything we can do to stop this ?

Comment: This is unfortunately not uncommon. There are some tips on how to handle it at http://serverfault.com/questions/257245/stopping-spam-related-bounced-emails

Comment: You're welcome! If you want to thank someone, an upvote is also a nice way of doing it :-)